# Displays the list of groups for a login using command-line in iMac

Tags: unix, login, user, imac, user-groups

How to display the list of groups for which login, contained in the environment variable ***FT_USER***, is a member (separated by commas without spaces) using ***Unix*** command line in ***iMac***.

Example:

```
forFT_USER=nours,the result is"god,root,admin,master,nours,bocal"(with-
out quotation marks)
```

This is how it should be like

```
 $>./print_groups.sh 
 god,root,admin,master,nours,bocal$>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
groups $FT_USER | tr ' ' ','
```

Both `groups` and `tr` are common unix utils.